# c# - Replicating a cURL call with Httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, curl, httpwebrequest

I've read other questions about this topic but they don't match my case.
This is the cURL call I want to translate:

```
curl -u "{username}":"{password}"   
     -F data=@data.csv
     -F metadata="{\"language\":\"en\",\"name\":\"Title\"}"
     "https://example.com"
```

I know how to set credentials and the method for the requested url, but i don't know how to move forward. They seem to be two files: csv the first one, json the second one.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://example.com");
request.Method = "POST";                
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```